# VBA locate the first empty cell that occurs in a row by moving left/right

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a `Row` in `Excel` and many cells of that row are populated by numbers, dates, etc.

Let us say this is `Row 1`. However once we make a couple of moves in `Row 1` to the left we find 3 or 4 empty cells and then continuing our move to the left on `Row 1` the cells are populated again by various values.

**How can i go to the first cell which is blank and empty that occurs, when we move to the left in `Row 1` every time i fire up a macro?**

```
.____.____.___.___.___.____.____.____.____.____.
|_d__|_d__|___|___|___|__x_|_d__|_d__|_d__|_O__|
```

To put this schematicall **if we are** on `O` how can we **find/go** to `x`?

(Lets assume the `x` is the first blank cell)

How can i go here
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should move the selection there.

```
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0,-1).Select
```